# CountVectorizer is not respecting the regex

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using the following code to get the document term matrix:

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)


class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc: ([stemmer.stem(w) for w in analyzer(doc)])

stemmed_count_vect = StemmedCountVectorizer(stop_words='english', 
                                            ngram_range=(1,1), 
                                            token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', 
                                            min_df=1, 
                                            max_df=0.6)
```

However, I'm still getting items like these:

```
20009
2000mile
20011
20017
2001Ã¢
2007s
20081007
200h
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern `token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b'` says it wants one or more members of the `\w` character class between word boundaries. This character class

> [m]atches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore.

So it seems to me you need less inclusive character class (leaving out digits for a start).